# jQuery Plugins/Validation

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using the jQuery form validator from http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#Validator

How do I sto other input buttons from validating.

input button 1: validates the form
input button 2: must not validate

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most browsers, the default action for `<button>` or `<input type="button">` is submit, and jQuery Validation validates on submit. You can use `<button type="button">` instead. Clicking this kind of button does not validate the form.

It is recommendable to add `type="submit"` for button element even if you want it to submit, because the default type for `<button>` is different in some browsers.

Comment: I will mark your answer as accepted in spite of it is not right. But it lead me to another idea. I replaced the non-validating button to a linkbutton in asp.net, that means it is a javascript submit.

Comment: @user168507 could you point out which part of the answer is wrong? I can edit it if necessary

Answer (score 0):

According to the sample on that jQuery documentation page that you linked to, you simply set the class of the fields you want to have validated to "required". Ones without that class shouldn't validate. See how the class attribute value differs for each one below.

```
<label for="cemail">E-Mail</label>
<input id="cemail" name="email" size="25" class="required email" />

<label for="curl">URL (optional)</label>
<input id="curl" name="url" size="25" class="url" value="" />
```

Also, I've been quite pleased with this jQuery form plugin, which may be easier to customize: 
https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

Comment: thx for your feedback.

I have a aspx-Page, that is always wrapped in one(!) form tag.

I need a tipp how to stop another input button (i.e. id=inputBtn2) from validating. In other words I don't want inputBtn2 to start validation.

Comment: https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine is easier to config, but I need the original above plugin

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your original request. You may need to modify the original plugin so that it validates only onClick of your desired button and have it look for the nearest form element (possibly using parents()) to identify the necessary inputs.